# Need help understanding website database issues

Tags: html, asp.net, ms-access

I am hoping to understand the issues I am having with one of my web sites. Before I get into details, I want to say that web development was never my thing and I have taken over web duties of the company web site. Most of my work has been updating the site cosmetically.

Recently, our web host is changing server platforms and is requiring all their customers to migrate their web sites to the new platform, which has new software and compatibility. The provider said our current site would work on the new platform but since migrating our ASP files and their connection to our database files do not work. After consulting with the technicians at the web host, they said the following that leave me clueless.

> The connection string you need to use Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0 driver instead of Microsoft.Jet.OLDBD.4.0

First off, what is this driver connected to; what program. I use an older version of Microsoft Access to compile our database .mdb files that the web site uses and if the update needs to be done by updating the version, we can do that. But we do not want to unnecessarily do so.

Where would the connection string need to be placed? I looked through some of the older config files located on the web site and only found one that had a connection string in it. I changed that string to match what I assumed was required but it did not solve the problem.

Essentially the database file is not being read properly and we need to find out why, and more importantly how to fix it.

Keep in mind that I do not know much about how the database/asp.net files/html/web server works together, and the person who originally set up this environment is no longer around to ask, so its picking up the pieces literally from scratch.

EDIT

Here is some more information
First, this is the error:

> Microsoft Access Database Engine error '80004005'
>
> Unspecified error
>
> /config/include/LookupIndexPrices.asp, line 13

This is line 13:

```
GetRepRecordSet.Open "select * from  RepLinks where Initials = '" & strEnteredPwdRep & "'", ConnectString("CMPRepData")
```

When I asked our web host to help me solve the issue, the technician responded with the following:

The error message displayed for your web pages is due to the database connection error. I could see that you are using MS Access databases for your website. It seems that you are using Microsoft.Jet.OLDBD.4.0 driver for database connections. Your hosting account is hosted on our 2012 servers and it doesn't support the usage of old database driver. Please make sure to use the Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0 driver for the database connections in your scripts.

Where is this driver that needs updated, what is it affiliated or connected to, and how do I correct it to the updated version?

Comment: Connection string is likely placed (hopefully) in a web.config file or anywhere a database connection is being opened in your application.

Comment: so to sum up - you do not know anything about "database/asp.net files/html/web server " and with out hire some one to know, you believe that you can solve your problem ?

Comment: When something does not work in .net you will receive an Exception. You need to find where this exception is logged (a file or if not caught then in the event log). Copy the entire exception in your question above including the Message, the full type name, and the stack trace, if there is an inner exception then do the same for that inner exception recursively. This can better point to what is going wrong. If your question is closed (it most likely will be) update it with this information and if it is specific enough your question could be re-opened.

Comment: I added a little bit to the post to hopefully clarify things.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to find where `ConnectString("CMPRepData")` is stored.  This is the variable that contains your database connection string.

Next, you need to update this connection string to use the `ACE OLEDB 12.0` driver.

**Example (from [ConnectionStrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/))**

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\myAccessFile.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;
```

Comment: I guess this is where I get confused the most. I found a utils file that contains the connection string

Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + databasePath + ".mdb"

Of which I changed to the ACE...12... 

Its the only file associated with the documents that I can see this line in. I can't figure out what is next, as uploading this file to my web server does not help.

Comment: I was recently told the following

The Microsoft ACE OLEDB 12.0 is a OLE DB Provider is provided by Microsoft. The provider is contained in the file ACEOLEDB.DLL . 

I found the ACEOLEDB.DLL file on the computer I use to compile our database files via Access, but I am unsure how to get the entirety of things to work with the updated version.

Comment: @medrob Unfortunately, this is not necessarily the appropriate place to teach you how to program in Active Server Pages (ASP).  Your web host will already have the appropriate drivers installed.  No need to worry about DLLs.  You do, however, need to find where the correct connection string is, update it, upload the files to your server and try the app again.

Comment: I don't necessarily need anyone to teach me ASP stuff, I'm just trying to figure out why my web host is telling me that my ASP pages and my database files require something without telling me what, or where to get it properly. They are confusing me and it makes me frustrated, especially when everything worked on their old platform service months before.